# Non-Linear Differential Equation with quadractic terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have been doing some exercises about solving differential equations, but I am not be able to solve this one:

**Find the implicit solutions of the following DE
$$\dfrac{xx'}{\sqrt{x^2+r(x')^2}}=c,$$
with $r$ a positive constant and $c$ a real number**

I tried to find a suitable change of variable, but it has not worked.

Thanks in advance: Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(x')^2=\frac{c^2x^2}{x^2-c^2r}$

Comment: Does $r(x')^2$ mean that $r$ is constant multiplied times $x'$ squared? Alternatively, does $r(x')^2$ tells us that $r$ is a function of $x'$ squared, i.e. $r(x')^2=[r(x')]^2$?

Comment: $r$ is a positive constant. I am going to clear it out in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finding $x(t)$ by solving
$$xx'=c\sqrt{x^2+rx'^2} \implies x^2x'^2=c^2x^2+rc^2x'^2 \implies x'^2(x^2-rc^2)=c^2x^2$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\pm \frac{cx}{\sqrt{x^2-rc^2}} \implies \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{x} dx= \pm \int c ~dt  $$
Let $x=a~ sec~ u \implies dx=a ~sec~ u \tan u$, then
$$a \int \tan^2 u ~ du =\pm \int du \implies  a \int (sec^2 u -1) du =\pm ct+K$$ $$\implies a(\tan u-u)=\pm ct+K \implies \sqrt{x^2-a^2}-a ~sec^{-1}(x/a)=\pm ct+K,~ a=c\sqrt{r}$$

The sign $\pm$ will be fixed by the intial condition,

Comment: From the original equation you get $sign(x)sign(x')=sign(c)$, so that you can exclude the minus sign in the square root a few steps down the line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $f^2(x)=g^2(x) \implies $|f(x)|=|g(x)| \implies $f(x)=\pm g(x)$. I believe that $\pm$ sign will be fixed by initial condition.

Comment: What you say is true in general. But you start by squaring, so losing sign information that can be reconstructed from the original equation, no initial conditions needed. You get directly $sign(x')=sign(cx)$, the sign of the square root as function is always positive. There is no need for sign cases at any point.

Comment: Or if you want it organically, $x^2+rx'^2=x^2+\frac{rc^2x^2}{x^2-rc^2}=\frac{x^4}{x^2-rc^2}$, so that $xx'=\frac{cx^2}{\sqrt{x^2-rc^2}}$.